# How to override the value of a cookie rather than creating another cookie if the cookie key is the same in flask?

Tags: flask, cookies, httpcookie

I am currently working in flask. I have come across an issue:

Let's say I have a route set-cookie as follows:

```
@app.route('/set-cookie', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def set_cookie():
   resp = make_response()
   resp.set_cookie('name', 'John')
   resp.set_cookie('name', 'Henry')

   return resp
```

The issue with the above code is that the response header that the browser receives has duplicate keys for cookies:
[image]

Now, if the same key is duplicated multiple times, the response header will become considerably large. How to ensure that if the duplicate key is used in the same response, the flask server only sends one instance of the key with the latest value, i.e., the server should send only one cookie that has the key 'name' and value 'Henry'? Is there any native solution in flask for this issue?